# How does a computer perform any instruction without making a system call

Tags: c++, macos, unix, operating-system, system-calls

I am learning about Operating Systems and trying to get a deep understanding about the fundamentals about how a program works.

I have a simple C++ program

When I look at the basic architecture of Linux, it always shows User Space and Kernel space where the operating system accesses the hardware through device drivers.

So the way I see it any program i create needs to access the OS for every instruction if i am not mistaken especially when it is running in user space ?

But then I see this answer on another site:
https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/a/3463/14110

which mentions things that are purely computational do not make system calls, but then how do these access CPU, RAM etc ??

My basic understanding tells me, everything should make a system call, but now I see enough info that not not everything is a system call, so how does basic arithmetic or any other instruction that isn't a system call work ?

I know i am not getting into too many lower level details. But in a nutshell, how does this work
Please can someone explain?

Here is a diagram I created based on how I think it works, please feel free to correct:

[image: My basic diagram of Linux architecture]

Here is a simple C++ program that creates three variables in memory,
takes two numbers as input,
Adds the two numbers and places the value into the third and then displays the output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int x, y, z; // Create three variables and store them in memory, should make a system call
    printf("Enter first number: "); // Ask for User Input, I/O
    cin >> x; // I/O operation
    printf("Enter second number: ");
    cin >> y;
    z = x + y;
    printf("Total: %d \n", z);
    return 0;
}
```

Doesn't each of these instructions require system calls implicit or explicit ?

I read related questions,

The program works perfectly, but I want to know about system calls

Comment: A program does not need to make a system call to add 2 and 2 together, resulting in 4. This accomplishment is achievable without the need for any system call. In the shown code `z = x + y;` does not need a system call. The kernel has better things to do than to add numbers for you.

Comment: Your program is compiled into assembly instructions. Most of those run fine as is. There's no security issue in letting programs execute basic copy/math/logic instructions and memory accesses have hardware support to provide security.

Comment: Okay, so i just wanted to know how the program would access RAM and CPU ? Because that is hardware ? I am sure i am missing something basic and i am sure I will get downvote for this haha

Comment: The program's compiled machine code is largely run directly on the CPU. Simple instructions like adding numbers together, and accessing memory addresses of local variables stored on the call stack, are handled by the CPU not the OS.

Comment: The CPU limits and protects what RAM your process can access.

Comment: The execution of a program instruction by instruction does not count as hardware access that would need OS support.

Comment: The OS will set the program up with some piece of RAM and most instructions available, and let it go. If using addresses outside the allowed area, or trying to use some (just a few) priviliged instructions, the program will be interrupted and the OS takes over again.

Comment: Don't cross the streams.  If you use `std::cin`, use `std::cout`.  Use `printf` and `fscanf`.  If you really need format strings, see `std::format`.

Comment: A program may need to use an OS to manage resources, such as console access or file access.  You can transpose an image without using the OS except for I/O calls.  Embedded systems often access resources without using an operating system.

Comment: Consider that making a syscall involves executing at least one, and usually many more, instructions. How would that work if you can't execute any instructions other than by asking the OS to do so on your behalf?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The kernel allocates blocks (pages) of virtual memory for you (via a system call). Once the kernel has given you that page you are free to perform whatever operations you like within that page. Mathematical operations only need access to memory and registers to be performed, the kernel is not involved in user space code whilst it's just doing these kind of operations. As with the memory the program is free to use whatever instructions it needs (as long as it stays within its assigned memory pages).

At some point the kernel will want another process to run, when it does it'll interrupt the process, save its registers and resume the other process. This is basically transparent to the user space code though, and its execution will continue where it left off when the kernel restores its registers and resumes execution.

System calls are only required when accessing other hardware in the computer like the gpu, network card, storage etc.

Comment: Great thanks, So I guess based on my simple example all printf, scanf, cin, cout etc would involve syscalls as they are accessing I/O ?

Comment: Yes, they will involve system calls (unless they're just working on buffered data)